# Run shell script (.sh) from wine

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, cmd.exe, wine

I am new to the wine community.

I need some help with a project I am trying to do.
I have installed Wine over Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed ffmpeg on my machine (ffmpeg as a linux program).

I have created a .sh file that runs the ffmpeg screen recorder and saves my recording.

I would like to run this .sh file from wine.
Is there any way to do this?

I have tried the following:

> /bin/sh capture.sh

And get:

> Can't recognize 'capture.sh' as an internal or external command, or batch script.

My main application can run .bat and .cmd files.

Answer (score 0):

Convert capture.sh into a batch file. On another note, why not do say `capture.sh &; wine whatever.exe` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I convert capture.sh into a batch file then there is a problem with the x11 grab / Unknown input format: 'x11grab'
/ Because I think that ffmpeg runs through wine and not linux.

Comment: No, if ffmpeg is doing an x11 grab it is most definitely a linux binary. You'll need to start the screen recording either before or at the same time as the wine process, as demonstrated above, `capture.sh &; wine whatever.exe`

Comment: Yes I understand your reasoning but I would like to call the ffmpeg screen capture from within my application that runs on wine. Thus, I think that this is not possible with the above. On windows, I just call the .bat file that runs the process.